# Why do some OpenGL parameters take 0.0-1.0?

Tags: opengl

Why do some OpenGL parameters take a value between 0.0 and 1.0 for some functions like glColor3f and glNormal3? This is a question that has always sort of bugged me; I have always had since the beginning of my 3D programming career, but originally I just went along with it like any other sheep following the herd. But why 0.0-1.0? Was it an arbitrary choice made by the the Khronos Group, or something more existential?

Comment: Components of a unit normal vector are in the range -1 to 1 not 0 to 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because values less than 0 or greater than 1 don't make sense for those things.

For colors, the typical representation for display purposes is an 8-bit integer from 0 to 255, but OpenGL isn't limited to that specific representation; a GL implementation can also support things like 48-bit color (16 bits per channel), or floating-point color components.  To be independent of the underlying representation, color components in OpenGL are represented as fractions from 0% to 100%, which are expressed by the numbers 0.0 and 1.0.  The GL implementation converts those values into whichever format is actually used by the display (e.g. the typical 0-255).

Normals are supposed to be unit-length vectors, which means that the length of each component naturally can't be greater than than 1; otherwise the length of the whole vector would be greater than 1.

Note that these values don't *actually* have to be in the 0.0-1.0 range:

- For colors, your monitor can't actually *display* a brightness greater than 100%, but a color component greater than 1.0 can be useful if it's going to be multiplied by something (e.g. a texture or scaling factor) that'll bring it back into range.  This is commonly used for [HDR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-dynamic-range_rendering) rendering.
- Non-unit-length normal vectors aren't really useful for the legacy fixed-function lighting that it sounds like you're using, since they don't correspond to real-world physics, but you can specify them anyway and you'll get results that are mathematically correct (though not realistic or useful).  You can also specify non-unit-length normals and ask OpenGL to automatically scale them to unit length using `GL_NORMALIZE`.

  Non-unit-length vectors can be useful in programs that use custom shaders to perform sophisticated lighting calculations.